# Is there any way to write custom HTML is some .php file and then call it wherever necessary?

Tags: templates

I'm an absolute newbie as far as wordpress and php are concerned.So I wanna write some custom HTML and re use it again and again just like 'headers' and 'footers'.I have googled a lot but haven't find anything useful.Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

or a PHP include `<?php include("file.php"); ?>`